# Fixed element with lower z-index overlaps scrollbar in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox, cross-browser

I created a scrollable list of divs with one fixed element at the bottom.
The list should overlap the fixed div when the height is too small.
It works in Chrome, but in Firefox the fixed div overlaps the scrollbar (and only the scrollbar) from the list.

**Why is this the case and how can I resolve this issue?**

**[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdfxpxer/)**

```css
.menuehead{
  background: #DDD;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.scrolldiv{
  height: calc(100vh - 42px);
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 42px;
  background: #AAA;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 1002;
}
.scrolldiv .fixed.item{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: #DDA;
  width: 198px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.scrolldiv :nth-child(2n)
{
  background: #ADD;
}
.scrolldiv :nth-child(2n-1)
{
  background: #DAD;
}
.item{
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  height: 42px;
  min-height: 42px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 3;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuehead">HEAD</div>
<div class="scrolldiv">
  <div class="item">FIRST</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">LAST</div>
  <div class="item fixed">FIX</div>
</div>
```

The wrong yellow div (from the snippet) in Firefox 58.0.1:
[image]

Comment: For me it works the same on firefox and chrome. If the height is too small, the list overlap the  the fixed div

Comment: @AlexVand I added a picture I took from the snippet view of the bug in Firefox

Comment: What if you set   overflow-x: hidden;on the scroll div ?

Comment: @AlexVand unfortunatelly no effect

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue ... this was just a thing i was thiking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since also Edge render the `.item.fixed` on top of the scrollbar, I am not sure if it is Firefox/Edge or Chrome who is correct.

As the scrollbar actually belongs to the `scrolldiv`, I think Chrome is wrong.

As the `.item.fixed` is a child of `.scrolldiv`, and should be positioned at its bottom, instead use `position: absolute`, and you'll get the same result cross browsers, where the scrollbar is fully visible.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdfxpxer/5/)

Stack snippet

```css
.menuehead{
  background: #DDD;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.scrolldiv{
  height: calc(100vh - 42px);
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 42px;
  background: #AAA;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 1002;
}
.scrolldiv .fixed.item{
  position: absolute;                  /*  changed  */
  bottom: 0px;
  background: #DDA;
  width: 100%;                         /*  changed  */
  box-sizing: border-box;              /*  added  */
  z-index: 2;
}
.scrolldiv :nth-child(2n)
{
  background: #ADD;
}
.scrolldiv :nth-child(2n-1)
{
  background: #DAD;
}
.item{
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  height: 42px;
  min-height: 42px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 3;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuehead">HEAD</div>
<div class="scrolldiv">
  <div class="item">FIRST</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">LAST</div>
  <div class="item fixed">FIX</div>
</div>
```